# inserting data into MySQL from android app

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am going to develop a web application for android but I am trying first time ever this experiment so i am not able to complete my task because I am new in it. Its giving me an error like string cannot convert to JSONObject. please please help me I've tried everything upto me but could not get any solution yet. Here is my code.

```
public class signup extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button signup,cancel;
EditText e1,e2,e3,e4;

String name;
String email;
String  mobile;
String passwd;
InputStream is=null;
String result=null;
String line=null;
int code;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signupfrag);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    signup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.reg);
    cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.regcancel);

    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.uid);
    e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.contact);
    e4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwd); 

    signup.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId()==R.id.reg)
    {
        name = e1.getText().toString();
        email = e2.getText().toString();
        mobile = e3.getText().toString();
        passwd = e4.getText().toString();

        insert();
      Intent i=new Intent(signup.this,MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(i);
    }

    if(v.getId()==R.id.regcancel)
    {
      e1.setText(null);
      e2.setText(null);
      e3.setText(null);
      e4.setText(null);
    }
}
private void insert() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname",name));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile",mobile));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passwd",passwd));

        try
        {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.43.73/htdocs/insert1.php");//10.0.2.2
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    }
        catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }     

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    }
        catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }     

    try
    {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

            if(code==1)
            {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        Log.e("log_tag", "Failed data was:\n" + result);
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }       
  }
}
```

and this is my php code

```
<?php
$host='127.0.0.1';
$uname='root';
$pwd='password';
$db="resumemaker";


$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

$fname=$_REQUEST['fname'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$mobile=$_REQUEST['mobile'];
$passwd=$_REQUEST['passwd'];



$flag['code']=0;

if($r=mysql_query("insert into sample values('$fname','$email','$mobile','$passwd') ",$con))
{
    $flag['code']=1;
    //echo"hi";
}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks In Advance....

Comment: What is giving that error the PHP or...(c#?)? Your PHP currently is open to SQL injections.

Comment: its showing me error in logcat log 07-06 00:29:46.022: E/Fail 3(686): org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
I am not able to understand what to do with this code

Comment: That doesn't seem like a PHP error. Is that first bit of code java? Might want to add that tag to this question. Also you should resolve the SQL injection in your PHP code and switch over to the `mysqli` or `pdo` driver.

Comment: I think here it is error
    try
      {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            code=(json_data.getInt("code"));
            if(code==1)
            {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
      }       
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are not encoding it into json see this example will help you its 100% percent working code

Index.php

```
<?php

   header("Content-Type:application/json");

   include("function.php");

$fname=$_REQUEST['fname'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$mobile=$_REQUEST['mobile'];
$passwd=$_REQUEST['passwd'];

 $record = fetchrecord($fname,$email,$mobile,$passwd);


         if(empty($record))
         {
           deliverresponse(200,"Record not found",NULL,0);  
         }
         else
         {
           deliverresponse(200,"Record Displayed",$record,1);   
         }


   function deliverresponse($status,$status_message,$data,$success)
   {
         header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");
         $response['status'] = $status;
         $response['status_message'] = $status_message;
          $response['code'] = $code;
          $response['data'] = $data;
          $jsonresponse = json_encode($response);
          echo $jsonresponse;

   }
?>
```

Function.php

```
<?php
        $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

        mysql_select_db('your db name', $conn);

  function fetchrecord($fname,$email,$mobile,$passwd)
  {


     $qur = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `sample` (fname,email,mobile,passwd) VALUES (NULL, '$fname','$email','$mobile','$passwd')") or die ("Query Failed");

     if($qur)
     {
        $msg = "Record Inserted";   

        $user[] = array($msg); 

     }
     else
     {
       $msg = "Record not Inserted";   

        $user[] = array($msg);   
     }
        return $user;

  }
```

use Async Class for net threading

```
 public class SignupProcess extends  AsyncTask<String, String, String>

    {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
   private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "code";
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(signup.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Login..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {




            List<NameValuePair> pair = new ArrayList<>();
            pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mobile));
            pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status",String,psswd);


            json = JSONParser.makeHttpRequest("http://xxxxxxx","GET", pair);

            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            try {

                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                getstatus = success;
                if (success == 1) {

                    Log.d("success!", json.toString());

                }

                else if (success==0){


                    return json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    public static String Result=null;

    public JSONParser()
    {

    }

    public static JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url,String method, List<NameValuePair>  pair) {

        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method.equals("POST")){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pair));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method.equals("GET")){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(pair, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, HTTP.UTF_8), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Result = json;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jObj;
    }


}
```

On Button click listener write

```
new SignupProcess().execute();
```